# Newly-created SSH keys landed in my home folder rather than `.ssh` folder after creating with `ssh-keygen`

Tags: terminal, high-sierra, ssh, encryption

I used the `ssh-keygen` utility bundled with High Sierra to create keys, as directed by this page title [*How to Create SSH Keys with OpenSSH on Linux or macOS*](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/droplets/how-to/add-ssh-keys/create-with-openssh/) at DigitalOcean.com.

Oddly, the prompt to save the new file for keys indicated the `.ssh/id_rsa` folder. Yet, the new keys were found in my home folder.

Here is my session, replacing a couple things with `blah_blah_blah`.

I entered a file name of `acme`. The pair of files named `acme` & `acme.pub` were saved to my home folder of `/Users/basilbourque`, not `.ssh`.

```
MacBook-Pro:~ basilbourque$ which ssh-keygen
/usr/bin/ssh-keygen
MacBook-Pro:~ basilbourque$ ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/basilbourque/.ssh/id_rsa): acme
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in acme.
Your public key has been saved in acme.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:blah_blah_blah basilbourque@MacBook-Pro.local
The key's randomart image is:
blah_blah_blah
```

➥ Any idea why the destination path indicated in the prompt was ignored?

One possible issue: There is no `id_rsa` folder nested in my `.ssh` folder, only a `known_hosts` file is found there.

I ask for two reasons:

- Mere curiosity.

  - Why would the `ssh-keygen` utility display a path in the prompt if it is going to ignore that path?
  - Why would the `ssh-keygen` utility display a path to a non-existent folder?
- Wondering if this will result in the ssh connection tool failing to find and utilize the keys for logging into a new ssh connection session.

Is there some place I should move these keys so that will be found by the ssh connection tool? (I am new to using ssh.)

Answer (score 3):

You are prompted for a file name, not a folder name (`Enter **file** in which to save the key`). So if you just reply with a file name the keys will be stored (with that name) in the current directory. You can just move them to `.ssh/` manually if necessary. You probably also need to tell ssh to use your keys instead of the default ones (or you rename your keys to the default name).

Comment: (A) I did enter a file name, `acme` in the text seen in my Question. Why the is this path `/Users/basilbourque/.ssh/id_rsa` in the prompt for the file name if the keys will land in the current directory? And why a path to a non-existent folder? (B) I have no idea what you might mean by a default name or default key. That makes no sense to me as a person might be ssh-ing into any number of different servers each with a different key.

Comment: @BasilBourque It asks for a file, not a folder.

Comment: @BasilBourque Please read up on how ssh works. You create one key pair for your computer and copy the public key to the authorized_keys file on the machines you want to log in to. At least for simple operations there is no need to create several key pairs on the same machine.

Comment: Because /Users/[USERNAME]/.ssh/id_rsa is the default name and path for your ID file. Just like saving in many other programs suggests a name and location, ssh_keygen tries to save your ID as file "id_rsa" in folder /Users/[USERNAME]/.ssh

Comment: If you give it a different name and don't include path, it saves to current directory. You entered "acme", not "/Users/basilbourque/.ssh/acme"